# Build a Linux executable using GCC

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ubuntu, executable

I'm using [Ubuntu 8.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_8.10_(Intrepid_Ibex)) (Intrepid Ibex) and compiling C++ files with GCC, but when I compile, gcc makes an `a.out` file that is the executable. How can I make Linux executables?

Comment: What is the difference for you between an executable and a Linux executable ?

Comment: can you clarify?  The `*.out` files are the executables.  Do you need another type of executables?

Comment: Nathan, the 'a.out' name is a historical artifact, from the earliest Unix compilers. See the Wikipedia article on the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out

Comment: @notnoop: It's just `a.out`, not `*.out`. (Greetings from the future!)

Comment: `a.out` should already be executable. No need to do anything else. Just run with `./a.out`

Comment: Related: *[How can I compile and run C/C++ code in a Unix console/Mac terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221185/)*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That executable is a "Linux executable" - that is, it's executable on any recent Linux system. You can rename the file to what you want using

```
rename a.out your-executable-name
```

or better yet, tell GCC where to put its output file using

```
gcc -o your-executable-name your-source-file.c
```

Keep in mind that before Linux systems will let you run the file, you may need to set its "executable bit":

```
chmod +x your-executable-name
```

Also remember that on Linux, the extension of the file has very little to do with what it actually is - your executable can be named `something`, `something.out`, or even `something.exe`, and as long as it's produced by GCC and you do `chmod +x` on the file, you can run it as a Linux executable.

Comment: Doesn't gcc (in fact the linker it calls) already set the executable bit in its output file?

Comment: @CesarB: Yes, the gcc call makes 'your-executable-name' executable by default.

Comment: Some systems might have a `rename` command, but `mv` is the usual way to rename a file.

Comment: Conversely it may or may not set too much: `-rwxrwxr-x`.

Answer (score 4):

To create an executable called `myprog`, you can call *gcc* like this:

```
gcc -c -o myprog something.c
```

You could also just rename the *.out file *gcc* generates to the desired name.

Answer (score 3):

That is the executable. If you don't like *a.out*, you can pass an *-o* flag to the compiler. If the executable isn't marked with an executable bit, you need to do so yourself:

```
chmod u+x ./a.out
./a.out
```

Comment: The *.out file already is an executable, but how i can build a native Linux executable, linux native executables don't have extensions.

Comment: In linux, extensions don't matter.  You can just rename the file to anything you like.

Comment: When the problem is permition i know. Thanks!