# This very simple C++ program using the standard library doesn't compile with GCC

Tags: c++, cout

I can't figure out why this isn't working...

I am working in Linux.

`g++` doesn't do anything.

`gcc` prints the following:

```
/tmp/ccyg7NDd.o: In function `main':
test.cc:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `std::cout'
test.cc:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
test.cc:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
test.cc:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))'
/tmp/ccyg7NDd.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test.cc:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
test.cc:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccyg7NDd.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    std::cout << "test " << std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean that g++ doesn't do anything?

Comment: `gcc` is the C compiler, you need to use `g++`. What do you mean `g++` does not do anything? You have to execute the compiled binary after you build it (i.e. when `g++` completes).

Comment: @hmjd: g++ **is** gcc, it just automatically links against libstdc++.  You can get the same effect with gcc by supplying `-lstdc++`.

Comment: What @hmjd said: after running `g++` you want to run the file which, with no other options, is called `a.out`.

Comment: by it doesn't do anything I mean it doesn't print to the console...which i think it should

Comment: @spatara: The compiler will only print something if there's a problem. Like most Unix-style programs, silence means success. You should find a program called `a.out`, or something else if you gave a `-o` option to the compiler; running that should print `test ` to the console.

Comment: @spatara If you don't like the silence, you can pass the `--verbose` flag and it'll tell you more than you want to know.

Comment: g++ dosen't do anything? Look at the new file in the folder. Not doing anything is compilation success!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
g++ main.cpp
```

or

```
gcc main.cpp -lstdc++
```

Answer (score 22):

`gcc` is the C compiler. You need to use `g++` (or use `gcc` with option `-lstdc++` as pointed out by others). If by nothing is printed after you use `g++` is what you mean, you have to execute the compiled binary after you build it (i.e., when `g++` completes).

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    std::cout<<"test "<<std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Build:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

Execute:

```
./main
```

Output:

```
test
```

Answer (score 5):

This is C++ code and so you should use executable `g++` and not executable `gcc`.

Also, `#include<stdio.h>`, is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistakenly linking with the C compiler command instead of the C++ compiler command. Try this:

> g++ test.cc -o test

Answer (score -1):

I think the underlying issue for this is that the binary name "test" is actually already apart of the Linux system. Typing in "man test" displays a manual for the test binary. I had the *exact* same issue. It was resolved simply by compiling the binary to something other than "test".

Comment: But the ***real*** issue was that "`test`" was used instead of "`./test`"(?). The canonical question is *[How can I compile and run C/C++ code in a Unix console or Mac terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221185/)*.