# How to install 'make' and GCC on a Mac

Tags: gcc, makefile, osx-lion, eclim

I want to install Eclim on my [MacBook Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air) (2011 version). But there are some problems I faced during the installation. It told me that I did not install make and GCC.

I tried to find the solution for it, but all solutions are talking about using [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode). In fact, I installed Xcode.

But I still cannot install Eclim because there are no make and GCC installed.

How can I install them so that I can install Eclim?

Comment: Related (a canonical question): *[How can I compile and run C/C++ code in a Unix console or Mac terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221185/)*

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Update for newer versions:

The command line versions can now be installed straight from the command line itself;

- Open "Terminal" (it is located in *Applications/Utilities*)
- In the terminal window, run the command `xcode-select --install`
- In the windows that pops up, click `Install`, and agree to the Terms of Service.

Once the installation is complete, the command line utilities should be set up property.

---

Older versions:

Installing recent Xcode versions confusingly enough does not automatically install the command line tools. To install the command line tools when they're not automatically installed;

- Start Xcode.
- Go to Xcode/Preferences.
- Click the "Downloads" tab.
- Click "Components".
- Click "Install" on the command line tools line.

That will install the command line tools and make them accessible from a regular command line.

Comment: Not correct anymore. Please refresh for the new XCode

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: My current make version on mac is 3.81. How do I upgrade to 4.1? thx

Answer (score 20):

With Homebrew installed on my Mac, the installation was as simple as running the command

`brew install make`

It might require root permissions.

Comment: I guess the latest version of gcc can be installed with brew too, with the command `brew install gcc`.
But then you may need to add a path to enable these installations to be picked up at runtime by your computer. Like `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` for gcc and `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` for make.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [this](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) standalone GCC installed (got from Xcode).

Comment: Apple has their own officially supported version now too you can download from [developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads) with a free developer account. Kenneth details it [here](https://medium.com/kr-projects/6e54e8c50dc8)

Answer (score 1):

With modern Xcode (4.3) you will need to run the GUI and have it install the command line tools.  I'll quote from the MacPorts [ProblemHotList](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist) because I have it bookmarked:

> Xcode 4.3 does not include a fully working set of command line tools by default. Nothing will build without it, despite the fact that `xcode-select` and `which make` may return correct values.
>
> You must open Xcode, go to Preferences, and download this component from the Downloads section. You will require an Apple ID to download the component.

Comment: Thx a lot, but it requires the developerID @@

Comment: Signing up as a developer for this purpose is free (not the $99 developer license for the Mac App Store or iTunes Store).

Comment: There are also other reasons why it might not be possible to use the Apple version: `/Users/uname/Documents/openwrt/include/toplevel.mk:29: *** Please use a newer version of GNU make. The version shipped by Apple is not supported.  Stop.`

Comment: This post goes through GNU Make on macOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901894/how-can-i-install-a-newer-version-of-make-on-mac-os