# Hello World in C++ says "Nothing More to be Done"

Tags: compilation, c++

I have no C++ experience and want to learn. I have XCode but the IDE
confuses me and seems far too advanced for my current level.

I'm starting with this http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/

```
// my first program in C++

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

I entered it into SublimeText2 using the C++ formatting and then saved the file in

```
Ryan>Desktop>ApplicationDevelopment>Sandbox as helloworld.cpp
```

I have XCode installed and found [How to run C/C++ in a Unix console/Mac terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221185/how-to-run-c-c-in-a-unix-console-mac-terminal)

I went to terminal, navigated to the directory it is in and tried:

```
make helloworld.cpp
```

It returned:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'helloworld.cpp'
```

Update, hopefully the below formatting is clear

> $ g++
>
> i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: no input files
>
> $ g++ helloworld.cpp -o outputname.bin
>
> $ (nothing returned)
>
> $ g++ helloworld.cpp helloApp ./helloApp
>
> i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: helloApp: No such file or directory
>
> i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: ./helloApp: No such file or directory
>
> $ g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloApp ./helloApp
>
> ld: in ./helloApp, can't link with a main executable
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status