# How to compile and run C program on Mac OS X

Tags: c

I am learning C and wish to write the program using a text editor on my Mac (running [OS X v10.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Lion) (Lion)).

I write the `.c` file, and compile it using `gcc filename.c` - which creates executable file called `a.out`. However, when I type `a.out` or `/a.out`, I get the following messages:

> -bash: a.out: command not found`or`-bash: /a.out: 
> No such file or directory

I have successfully compiled and ran C programs on Linux systems before using this same method. What am I doing wrong on my Mac?

Comment: The canonical question is *[How can I compile and run C/C++ code in a Unix console or Mac terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221185/)*.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to add a dot to indicate that the executable is in the current directory, as the current directory is not in the path:

```
./a.out
```

Comment: @JTWheeler, you might also consider naming your object file as this would prevent a.out from being overwritten when compiling multiple C programs manually in the same directory.



Do `gcc myprog1.c -o myprog1.o` and run it by doing `./myprog1.o`. Just a suggestion.

And alternatively you could use clang instead of gcc for you practice code as it gives better error details.

Answer (score 18):

You need to precede `a.out` with `./` as follows:

```
./a.out
```

Additionally, you may find it useful to change the name of the resultant executable. Example:

```
gcc nameofprogramyouwrote.c -o whatyouwanttheprogramtobenamed
```

...then execute it like this:

```
./whatyouwanttheprogramtobenamed
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to add a dot in front of the slash:

```
./a.out
```

`/a.out` would try to execute a program in the root folder (`/`).
`a.out` will look for your program in all the folders defined in the PATH environment variable.

> I have successfully compiled and ran C programs on Linux systems
>   before using this same method. What am I doing wrong on my Mac?

You have to do the same on Linux.

Answer (score 6):

To build:

```
    gcc -Wall -o yourFile yourFile.c
```

Then to execute:

```
    ./yourFile
```

Comment: always wondered for generating an executable with the name of C file. +1

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to set your permissions executable with *chmod +x a.out*.

Comment: gcc does it for you... Do not need to run chmod

Comment: Correct, but this is good practice as not everyone is using gcc.

Comment: Is this any different from `chmod 777 a.out`?

Comment: Yes, chmod 777 will make executable, readable, writable, deletable for everyone with access on the system.

Comment: [chmod 777](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/). [chmod 755](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-755/) or [chmod 744](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-744/) may be closer, but `u+x` is better

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a compiler. The easiest way, however, is to install Xcode. This way you'll get access to [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection).

Thus,

```
gcc -o mybinaryfile mysourcefile.c
```

Then run it like this.

```
./mybinaryfile
```

Answer (score 0):

But you forgot the dot,

```
./a.out
```

also you can just use cmake to compile your C program into binary if `./a.out` doesn't work!

Comment: Thes first part of your answer has already been given an upvoted more than once 9 years ago. The second part makes no sense. `a.out` is already a binary. And cmake changes nothing on that. Please, when answering old questions, be sure to bring new information that was not already given in the previous answers.