# How make a Mac App with a single .out file from C?

Tags: c, macos

I am learning C, and I can output `.out` files that run just fine.

In Windows, if you the file contains the `main` entry function, you can make an exe out of it.

In Mac... how is it in Mac? I know that an App is a package, but, what are the steps exactly, given one single `.out` file?

Answer (score 0):

[How to compile and run C program on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887947/how-to-compile-and-run-c-program-on-mac-osx)

You could use a tool like [Platypus](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus) to create an application bundle if you like (might be overkill). Or you could use [Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=work-automator) to create an application to call your complied `.out` file. I think you probably want to build some GUI, so you could use something like [GTK+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK+).