# gcc compile errors when c++ code is sound

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors, undefined-reference

My last question on here had issues that apperently were gcc not the code(code errors were solved and then I noticed issues with gcc ). I have since whipped up a short hello world program that I know is sound to test this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
}
```

but gcc still throws errors.

I named the file "test.cpp" and stored it directly in my home folder then tried:

```
gcc ./test.cpp -o Test

gcc ~/test.cpp -o Test

gcc /home/josh/test.cpp -o Test
```

All 3 times with and without capitalizing "Test".

Gcc gives the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccre0DEJ.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
test.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >        (std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >         (std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccre0DEJ.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My question is: How can I fix Gcc? If not should I try another compiler?

EDIT: I have tried reinstallint gcc and it still fails.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here. Also spend a bit more efforts with researching before asking questions here please.

Comment: Compilation errors are printed, not thrown.

Answer (score 1):

O.K. this was a duplicate (I can usually catch that before posting).

The answer was found here: [undefined reference to 'std::cout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236870/undefined-reference-to-stdcout)

I had to use

```
g++ ~/test.cpp -o Test
```

instead of

```
gcc ~/test.cpp -o Test
```

---

NB: Actually, it is better to compile with all warnings and debug info, that is to add 
 `-Wall -Wextra -g` to your `g++` or `gcc` command. Read more about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

Comment: Take the habit of compiling with all warnings and debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g ~/test.cpp -o Test`

Comment: I'm not ganna remember that but I typed it up for a reference until I do lol.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run g++ or add 'cpp flags' to the command, for example -lstdc++  which will link the code with the standard library of c++.

gcc can compile cpp code but only with the right flags.