# building c++ file with gcc throwing error while with g++ not

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, building

I am exploring vscode. when i am building file with gcc then is is throwing error while with g++ it is successfull.can anyone explain the reason.below is with g++

Starting build...
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\Nikhil Kumar\VS Project\DSA_Practice\kadane.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Nikhil Kumar\VS Project\DSA_Practice\kadane.exe"

Build finished successfully...while below is with gcc

Starting build...
C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\Nikhil Kumar\VS Project\DSA_Practice\kadane.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Nikhil Kumar\VS Project\DSA_Practice\kadane.exe"
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\NIKHIL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsbjjAr.o: in function `main': C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:6: undefined reference to` std::cout'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:6: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:7: undefined reference to` std::cin'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:7: undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(int&)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:9: undefined reference to` std::cout'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:9: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:11: undefined reference to` std::cin'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(int&)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:22: undefined reference to` std::cout'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:22: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:22: undefined reference to` std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:22: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Nikhil Kumar/VS Project/DSA_Practice/kadane.cpp:22: undefined reference to` std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\NIKHIL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsbjjAr.o: in function `_tcf_0': c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/iostream:74: undefined reference to` std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\NIKHIL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsbjjAr.o: in function `_static_initialization_and_destruction_0': c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/iostream:74: undefined reference to` std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: [undefined reference to `std::cout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236870/undefined-reference-to-stdcout)

Answer (score 2):

gcc is not the c compiler, it is "gnu compiler collection". As this, calling gcc with a cpp file will call internally the g++ to compile the file. But as a result you get a *.o file. And now you link all the stuff with the gcc-c-compiler. This is possible at all, but it did not link to the c++stdlib.so/a file. If you link with gcc you need to manually add c++stdlib. But it is highly recommended to use g++ for compile AND link!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc    kindly read the second answer its saying gcc is c compiler.

Comment: @Nikhil: However, calling gcc with a cpp file will result in compiling the file as c++ source code. But linking the objects later will fail if standard c++ libs are required, typically if stl is in use. As written there, it is a single entry point and `gcc -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc` is the same as calling `g++`. Maybe my english s not such clear...