# Why am I getting "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: c++

I am a complete beginner to c++. I am learning c++ through the [object oriented programming Data structures in c++](https://www.coursera.org/learn/cs-fundamentals-1). In the course I have the following program

**Cube.h**

```
#pragma once

class Cube {
  public:
    double getVolume();
    double getSurfaceArea();
    void setLength(double length);

  private:
    double length_;
};
```

**Cube.cpp**

```
#include "Cube.h"

double Cube::getVolume() {
  return length_ * length_ * length_;
}

double Cube::getSurfaceArea() {
  return 6 * length_ * length_;
}

void Cube::setLength(double length) {
  length_ = length;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cube.h"

int main() {
  Cube c;

  c.setLength(3.48);
  double volume = c.getVolume();

  std::cout << "Volume" << volume << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When I make this program with `make main`, I get the following error message

```
c++     main.cpp   -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Cube::getVolume()", referenced from:
      _main in main-6c5fe0.o
  "Cube::setLength(double)", referenced from:
      _main in main-6c5fe0.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am working from a macbook. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221185/how-to-compile-and-run-c-c-in-a-unix-console-mac-terminal) to run cpp programs in mac.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. An explanation to the error will also be nice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, you should complie also the Cube.cpp, like c++ *.cpp -o main.

Comment: its an interesting zoo of answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221185/how-to-compile-and-run-c-c-in-a-unix-console-mac-terminal). for some reason all assume that you compile a single source file and don't apply in your case

Comment: @idclev463035818 sorry for the ignorance. As I explained in the question, I am complete beginner and do not yet understand the errors. Have learnt this now

Comment: @Sashaank no need to be sorry. Maybe the authors of the answers should be ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **link** `main.cpp` and `Cube.cpp` together, so you have to compile with:

```
c++ main.cpp Cube.cpp -o main
```